# What parameters are parsed the first in myBatis mapper, # or $ ones?

Tags: sql, xml, mybatis, mybatis-sql

I use a  tag in the mapper, and text in it contains some external #{} parameters:

```
<sql id="searchInInterval">
    (r01.start between to_date(#{${what}Date}, 'MMYYYY') and to_date(#{thirdDate}, 'MMYYYY'))
```

Later in the XML mapper, when I use it

```
<include refid="searchInInterval">
    <property name="what" value="first"/>
</include>
```

, what parameter will be parsed the first? # or $ one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`${}` (text substitution) is resolved first.

In case `${}` is inside a `<sql />` like your example, MyBatis tries to replace it when parsing the mapper file (i.e. during application startup).
If there is no matching properties found [1] in this phase, MyBatis tries to replace it by looking up the runtime parameters when the statement is executed.

[1] In addition to the `<property />` nested inside `<include />`, you can declare properties in the [configuration](https://mybatis.org/mybatis-3/configuration.html#properties) as well.